# How to print HTML using TXTEXTCONTROL

Tags: c#, txtextcontrol

I am working on window application. I am facing a problem to print a webpage or HTML using TXTEXTControl.
What I need to do is, Pass html to method and it will print.

```
public void PrintHtml(string html)
{ 
 PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
            textControl1.Text =html;
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "d:\\abc.pdf";
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Label", (int)textControl1.PageSize.Width, (int)textControl1.PageSize.Height);
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins((int)textControl1.PageMargins.Left, (int)textControl1.PageMargins.Right, (int)textControl1.PageMargins.Top, (int)textControl1.PageMargins.Bottom);
  pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;
 textControl1.Print(pd);
    }
```

Anyone, please guide me, how to print html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load html to print your html page.

```
    public void PrintHtml(string html)
    { 
textControl1.Load("your file path",StringStreamType.HTMLFormat)
     PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
                pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
                pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
                textControl1.Text =html;// this line not needed.
                pd.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "d:\\abc.pdf";
                pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Label", (int)textControl1.PageSize.Width, (int)textControl1.PageSize.Height);
                pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins((int)textControl1.PageMargins.Left, (int)textControl1.PageMargins.Right, (int)textControl1.PageMargins.Top, (int)textControl1.PageMargins.Bottom);
      pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;
     textControl1.Print(pd);
        }
```